# undefined method `each' for String using Hstore with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I faced with the following problem:
I am using rails 4 with Postgresql. I use awesome feature called **hstore** for storing sets of key/value pairs in my db.

**Record example:**

```
<Category id: 2, name: "Phone",..., additional_fields: {"ram"=>"2gb", "camera"=>"8mp"}>

>  Category.find(2).additional_fields.class
=> Hash
```

But inside my view (or even inside controller) this transforms to String!

```
 <% @category.additional_fields.class %>  # returns String
```

Controller:

```
def set_category
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

Because of this next piece of code causes an error

```
<% @category.additional_fields.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag key, key %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

> **undefined method `each' for** "\"ram\"=>\"2gb\", \"camera\"=>\"8mp\""**:String**

Full trace:

```
app/views/categories/_form.html.erb:21:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_categories__form_html_erb__671254231_94341970'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:699:in `fields_for'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1538:in `fields_for'
app/views/categories/_form.html.erb:20:in `block in _app_views_categories__form_html_erb__671254231_94341970'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:435:in `form_for'
app/views/categories/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_categories__form_html_erb__671254231_94341970'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
app/views/categories/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_categories_edit_html_erb___781726467_94347130'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__967049018__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__795012590__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `catch'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:55:in `process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What's @category? Please provide your controlle code to show what exactly you are storing in @caterory.

Comment: Added code from the controller

Comment: In your controller try setting ```@fields =  Category.find ...etc``` and check the class of @fields is what you expect before passing it through to the view

Comment: `@additional_fields = @category.additional_fields`

`puts @additional_fields, @additional_fields.class`

Will return:
`"ram"=>"2gb", "camera"=>"8mp"
String`

Comment: Are you doing anything in the model with the additional fields before saving or after loading? Any manual serialization of the hash?

Comment: it seems that `additional_fields` is transformed to into inspect form. or even to_s. You have to run the `pry_debug` or `debugger` in the code and step by step find out the place, where the transformation happens.

Comment: @RichardJordan thank you for your note! The problem was exactly with my model.

Answer (score 0):

In my case
I have just rollback migration and again execute it and after this problem is solved